# Can we transform multiple updateOne into a single query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array `orderProducts` which looks like this

```
orderProducts = [
  {_id: _id, color: 'blue', quantity: '2'},
  {_id: _id, color: 'red', quantity: '4'},
  ...
];
```

I have this loop of queries which does what i need to do, find the doc and subtract the quantity.

What i want to know if we can group this kind of operations into one query

EDIT: I want to send only one query to the database so everything fails if one of the queries fail

```
// Working example of the operation i need to do
await Promise.all(
  orderProducts.map(
    product => Product.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: product._id, 'colors.color': product.color },
      { $inc: { 'colors.$.quantity': -product.quantity } },
      { new: true },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const orderProducts = [
  {_id: 1, color: 'blue', quantity: '2'},
  {_id: 2, color: 'red', quantity: '4'},
  {_id: 3, color: 'red', quantity: '3'},
  {_id: 4, color: 'green', quantity: '4'},
  {_id: 5, color: 'red', quantity: '3'},
];

const run = async () => {
  const output = await Promise.all(orderProducts.map(async (product) => {
    const result = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: product._id, 'colors.color': product.color },
      { $inc: { 'colors.$.quantity': -product.quantity } },
      { new: true }
    )

    return result
  }))
  
  console.log(output)
}

run()
```